# PHP rounding my numbers?

Tags: php, json, rounding

I'm doing an API call which is being outputted in `JSON`,

The product field is `"ProductID":3468490060026049912`

I convert to PHP, `json_decode()`

Then I output the `"Product ID" = float(3.4684900600261E+18)`

It gets changed to a float which is rounded, I input this figure into MYSQL and it stays as the rounded figure.

How do I convert from JSON to PHP without it rounding, I need it correct to 19 digits?

Comment: Are you on 32bit PHP? And really? I can think of no possible reason you'd need product IDs that high.

Comment: Software company's idea not mine, anyways I fixed with ini_set('precision',19);  Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING flag int he $options parameter of json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). You will have a string, though.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to store these IDs as integers; it's not like you're going to do any maths on them.

Store them as strings, and you won't have any issues with precision, no matter how many digits they are.

The only reason you'd need to store these as integers is if you're using them as your primary ID field in the database and its doing auto-increment for new records.

This is also the correct way to handle storage for phone numbers, zip codes, and other data that is formatted as a number but is actually just an arbitrary sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The value is too big to be stored as an [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) on 32 bit machines (the maximum is about 2*10<sup>9</sup>), that's why PHP converts it to float.

On 64 bit machines PHP can be stored as integer but its value is really close to the limit (which is about 9*10<sup>18</sup>). Another ID that starts with `9` or is one digit longer doesn't fit and is converted by PHP to float.

But floating point numbers loose the least significant digits.

As a quick workaround you can pass `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` as the fourth parameter to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) but it doesn't fixes the source of the problem. You can encounter the same problem on the Javascript or the database code.

You better make "ProductID" a string everywhere. It is an identifier, anyway. You don't need to do math operations with it, just to store it and search for it.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed with setting `ini_set('precision',19);` at the top.

Comment: This is a workaround, not a fix. The fix is to load them as strings like Vincente suggests.

Comment: This is a workaround that doesn't work on 32 bit machines and on PHP 5 on Windows (no matter the hardware architecture). It doesn't work even where it apparently works because the values are close to the limit of 64 bit integer range. One digit longer IDs cannot be stored in 64 bit integers, are converted to float and their (4 or 5) least significant digits are lost.